# jhipster microservice with sseemitter 406 error

Tags: angular, spring-boot, server-sent-events

I had generated jhipster application with gateway uaa and a microservice. Now to run sse I added following controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class AvgResultNftController {

    private final CopyOnWriteArrayList<SseEmitter> emitters = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    @GetMapping(path = "/avgResultNft")
    public SseEmitter getAvgResultNft() {
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
        this.emitters.add(emitter);

        emitter.onCompletion(() -> this.emitters.remove(emitter));
        emitter.onTimeout(() -> {
            emitter.complete();
            this.emitters.remove(emitter);
        });
        return emitter;
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("unlikely-arg-type")
    @EventListener
    public void onAvgResultNft(AvgResultNft avgResultNft) {
        List<SseEmitter> deadEmitters = new ArrayList<>();
        this.emitters.forEach(emitter -> {
            try {
                emitter.send(avgResultNft);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                deadEmitters.add(emitter);
            }
        });
        this.emitters.remove(deadEmitters);
    }

}
```

I am publishing AvgResultNft on some event.

I had generated angular application and calling the controller like

```
let source = new EventSource('http://192.168.1.5:8080/proxta/api/avgResultNft', {withCredentials: true })
source.addEventListener('message', message => {
      console.log(message)
    });
```

I am getting 406 not acceptable error on calling eventSource. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it help you
 Add  `headers = "Accept=*/*"`
and   `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE` 
or `MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE`

```
@GetMapping(value = "/avgResultNft", headers = "Accept=*/*",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
    public SseEmitter getAvgResultNft() {
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
        this.emitters.add(emitter);

        emitter.onCompletion(() -> this.emitters.remove(emitter));
        emitter.onTimeout(() -> {
            emitter.complete();
            this.emitters.remove(emitter);
        });
        return emitter;
    }
```

But be careful, zuul 1.х does not support sse

[How to make Server sent events (SSE) work trough Zuul Proxy spring-boot 2.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53835804/how-to-make-server-sent-events-sse-work-trough-zuul-proxy-spring-boot-2-1-1)